# How to set data from arraylist to listview

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

This is my adapter class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

private List<HashMap<String, String>> aList=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
int[] to;
public MyAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> aList) {
    super(context, R.layout.layoutarray, aList);

    this.context = context;
    this.aList = aList;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}



HashMap<String, String> m;
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (null == convertView) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutarray, parent, false);
    }

    TextView title1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.posttitle);
    TextView description1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.postdesc);
    //TextView image1=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.postimage);
    TextView date=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.postdate);
    ImageView image1=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.postimage);

    title1.setText(aList.get(aList.get(0).get("Title")));
  // Picasso.with(context).load(m.get("Image")).into(image1);

    return convertView;
}
}
```

This is my Activity:

```
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.aa, container, false);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(getActivity());
    Firebase ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);



    final List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),aList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);





    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                for (DataSnapshot single : child.getChildren()) {
                    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) single.getValue();

                    namerc = (String) map.get("Namerc");
                    image = (String) map.get("Imagerc");
                    description = (String) map.get("Description");
                    title=(String) map.get("Title");

                    if (namerc!=null && description!=null && title!=null) {
                        String[] title1={title};
                        String[] desc1={description};
                        String[] name1={namerc};
                        String[] image1={image};

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      HashMap<String,String>data=new HashMap<String, String>();
                        for (int i=0; i<title1.length;i++) {
                            data.put("Title", title1[i]);
                            data.put("Desc",desc1[i]);
                            data.put("Name",name1[i]);
                            data.put("Image",image1[i]);
                        }
                        aList.add(0,data);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}


}
```

I want to set the values from my List to text view (which is a listiview).
but when i set it it is showing only first data in the listview. i am not understanding what is going wrong ,how to fetch all the data from List and set it to listview.
please help me to solve this..

Comment: May be your rootview which you are inflating having height match_parent rather than the wrap_content

Comment: Use `title1.setText(aList.get(aList.get(position).get("Title")));`.Suggest you Switch to recyclerview.

Comment: Thanks Ragunadhan it solved my problem, just edited yur answer like this. title1.setText(aList.get(position).get("Title"));

Comment: aList.add(0,data); this adds the new data to top of the list buddy :)

Comment: @Shivuday it adds to the list at index 0. also avoid calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` inside for loop

Comment: then where should i put adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() buddy

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are getting the same value each time. Get value for the right position in your adapter. Something like this:

```
title1.setText(aList.get(position).get("Title"));
```